# How to overwrite text written with outtextxy BGI C

Tags: c, bgi

I am writing some scripts using BGI and I am facing an interesting problem I do not know how to solve. Let us say I want to create a log pannel, where I want to write on window(using outtextxy() function) some events that happened in sofware (like delete, create etc). But I do not know how.

So far, I thought of floodfill the entire area where the text has been written, but it seems that is not working.

```
 floodfill(3.7*width_rectangle+1, height_rectangle*14.3+1, WHITE);
 setcolor(BLACK)
 outtextxy(x,y, char*);
```

I tried some other things, like having a stack that stores all logs and when a new event happens, I take last element, I write it in BLACK again (to overwrite the existing one) and then a push the event to the stack. But it seems that this is not working too.

Can anybody suggest me a way to write text over another text in BGI?

Comment: `floodfill()` isn't going to work. Cover the previous text with a rectangle. You can find its extent with `textheight()` and `textwidth()` (using a record of the previous string output). Or, if you want something more sophisticated, take a copy of the area before writing, so you can undo it later.

Comment: I thought of implementing a record with all logs that have been recorded, and once a new one is created, to overwrite the one from the top of the stack. 
Thanks mate ! I did it and it works beautifully!

Comment: Perhps you only need the most recent, not a stack of them.